# IntelliJ infinite building maven

Tags: java, maven, github, intellij-idea, discord

My IntelliJ IDEA is building for an infinite time like on the picture.

I tried to Invalidate/Restart but it doesn't help.
Also recreated the Project sometimes but no success...
It's a Maven Git project.
I use JDA of Discord and JDK 1.8

[Picture of endless building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCci.png)

That's my last idea.log: goo.gl/k8pYGi Sorry for the shortened link. Pastebin got blocked.

Comment: report a bug...

Comment: What does `idea.log` say?

Comment: Can you compile from the command line?  Does `mvn clean install` complete?